# Ionic Pipe Value not shown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've added a simple pipe to my Ionic app but it is not working as expected. 
Not sure what the problem could be (my other pipes are working..). I tried it with and witouth the NgZone function.

The code of the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/**
 * Generated class for the LinkOgImagePipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'linkOgImage',
})


export class LinkOgImagePipe implements PipeTransform {


  constructor(public http: Http, private ngZone:NgZone) {
  }

  transform(value: string) {

    var urlEncoded;  
    urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(value);  

    var requestUrl = "https://mywebsitefunction.com?pageurl=" + urlEncoded ;  



    this.http.get(requestUrl).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{

        let imageurl = data[0]['img'];

        console.log(imageurl);

        this.ngZone.run(() => {     
            return imageurl;  
        })

    })




  }
}
```

The following code is from the page.ts:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let newsitem of newsItems">
  <img src="{{ newsitem.link | linkOgImage }}"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      {{ newsitem.title }}
    </ion-card-title>
    <p>
      {{ removeHTMLInfo(newsitem.description ) }}
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I also tried getting the value as text instead of getting it into an image but that is also not working. The console.log from the pipe does show the correct values, but it is not showing up on frontend.e

Hope you guys can point me in the right direction!

Comment: When you say it's not working, what is happening? Is the HTTP request being made? Is it returning successfully?

Comment: Yes the HTTP request works fine. The console log shows the correct image url that is returned by the HTTP request. The only problem is when the pipe returns the value to the frontend, it is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an impure pipe ( a pipe that makes an HTTP request) U should do it as

```
 @Pipe({
  name: 'fetch',
  pure: false
})
```

[Link to documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#an-impure-caching-pipe)

Comment: Tried it but it results in a loop with the pipe crashing my browser.

Comment: Got it working by using the cached variable like the example in the documentation!